# JSTL taglib absolute url not resolved

Tags: java, jsp, web, jstl, taglib

JSTL taglib

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

works only in my child pages but not working in my main page where i included my child page using `jsp:include` tag. Could anybody please help what i am missing in my main page to make it works. The error which i got is

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:561)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
```